# NullPointerException in solr multicore

Tags: tomcat, lucene, solr, multicore

I'm configuring my solr for two cores and have got most of it working, but I'm getting this cryptic error.

First off, here's my solr.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<solr persistent="true">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="cars" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/data/cars" config="/etc/solr/home_cars/conf/solrconfig.xml" schema="/etc/solr/home_cars/conf/schema.xml" instanceDir="home_cars" />
  <core name="industrial" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/data/industrial" config="/etc/solr/home_industrial/conf/solrconfig.xml" schema="/etc/solr/home_industrial/conf/schema.xml" instanceDir="home_industrial" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

All of this seems fine. I believe I've set the proper permissions for all the locations, but still I get this error in catalina.out:

```
INFO: user.dir=/var/lib/tomcat6
Aug 8, 2010 2:03:27 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:173)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
        at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:52)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$3.call(SolrCore.java:1147)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Some [info] logs and then this one:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:173)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
        at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:52)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$3.call(SolrCore.java:1147)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I'm not a top cat in solr, java or tomcat (or much else for that matter, hehe). Any help is will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this happens because QueryElevationComponent's config doesn't exist. Try this:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

Comment: You are correct and awesome! A few obvious error messages later and everything working just fine. Thank you, Aillyn!

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me that I copied the previous solrconfig.xml, so the elevator.xml path reference was wrong.

If you started from the template search for:

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
 <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
 <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
 <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

And change it to:

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
 <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
 <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
 <str name="config-file">../../conf/elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

Assuming you're using all the default directories.

Comment: Thanks - I just ran into exactly the same problem and that fixed it :)